# Auto-correlation of signal

Tags: time-series, svm, prediction, autocorrelation

I'm building a support vector machine that needs to predict whether or not someone is having an epileptic seizure. I've been reading into auto-correlation and think it could be used to make usefull features. If I understand correctly it can be used to find if a signal is random or if it has patterns by checking how similar it is to itself.

My data consists of several signals that are measured every second (for example hearth rate and motion). I've used the following formula, from the wikipedia,  to calculate the auto-correlation:

[image]

This basically seems to be the dot product from a signal window with a previous window of that signal. I fail understand how this can indicate if there are any patterns in the signal. Wouldn't this simply become higher if there happen to be high values in the signal and not when the signal is similar to itself? Am I missing something, should some preprocessing be done or am I using a wrong formula?

Comment: Well, it will pick up periodicity, for instance. If the signal repeats itself each three seconds, for instance, then the autocorrelation at lag three seconds will be one. You really need to read some introductory book on time series modeling.  A very good one for you could be https://www.amazon.com/Time-Biostatistical-Introduction-Statistical-Science/dp/0198522266

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing something, should some preprocessing be done or am I
>   using a wrong formula?

Look into Pearson correlation: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient)

This is the formula used in particular in autocorrelation analysis. Just remember that X and Y are timeseries values shifted against each other by **n** lags.